# leveraging environment variables in SSIS process tasks

Tags: windows, ssis, ssis-2012

I'm using 7z to zip up some files in SSIS:
[image]

This works, but I need the date to be in the zip.  So I tried this:
[image]

In the command line, this works perfect.  In SSIS, it crashes.  This tells me that SSIS has issues calling command variables.  How do I get that date in there?  It is the current date (date of execution) I'm looking for.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you use an expression to put the date in the name and not use the `%DATE...` command variable at all?

Comment: can you show me how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will depend on the formatting you want to use for your string, but the way you add dynamic elements to your SSIS components is via the `Expressions` group in each item's Properties.  With you `Execute Process Task` transformation selected:

1. Click in the Expressions box - which will be empty - in properties and then click the `...` icon that appears to the right.
2. Click in the `Property` dropdown and select Arguments.
3. Click the `...` icon.
4. Enter your expression, checking it works by clicking `Evaluate Expression`.
5. That's it!  Click `OK` on everything and try to run your package.

[image]

You can get help all over the internet on how to build that expression.  If you just want `yyyy-mm-dd` then `left((DT_WSTR,50)getdate(),10)` is what you need for the date part and you can fill in the rest.

Remember that some characters need a `\` before it as they hold special meaning and need to be escaped.  So if you wanted to return `\\server\share` your expression would be `"\\\\server\\share"` etc.

---

Just to add, it looks like you are adding your date to your filename in `dd-mm-yyyy` format?  I would advise against this as it causes confusion between US and UK systems and when you have `yyyy-mm-dd Score Backup.zip` as your filename they will sort correctly in Windows Explorer, whereas with `dd-mm-yyyy` all the files for the first of each month will be at the top, regardless of month or year.

Comment: I agree with you, but the system is not capable of internationalization.  it is a US-only real estate map system, and all the other date fields are this way.  Thanks much tho.  I'll attempt this solution in a few hours.  Much thanks.